# Text file to Oracle db as tables and data - Conversion tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, oracle11g

I have a text file saved as table1.txt like belo

```html
slno Name course  description
1    abc   efg    some desscription
2    ral   maki   make description
3    jal   kor    description for jal kor
```

any tool available to create this as a oracle table like

> Table Name  -> table1
>   Columns     -> slno ,name, course, description
>   and the corresponding data

To be honest I am trying to do the examples from the book "Data analysis using SQL and Excel by Gordon Linoff" but the data is available for SQL server but not for Oracle. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small table like this you could use the "Text to DDL" option in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). It will do a pretty good job of determining the datatype of the fields. You can then take the DDL it comes up with and clean it up. It will also create associated insert statements for you. Be sure to choose Oracle as the database you are using.

That being said, for small datasets you could probably just fix up the datatypes to be Oracle instead of SQL server. Once you start getting into indexes and stuff like that it gets more complicated. But it would be easy for a few simple tables.

You could also take a look at [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/online). It may not be perfect, but should be good for your needs. This is assuming you have the source DDL and the associated insert statements. Good luck!

Comment: Got it. If you just need it to work through the book, you could consider setting up a local SQL Server Express DB. No charge for Express edition and it's really easy to install and setup.

Comment: Ok Thanks.. Matt :)